# Старт ОС SlackWare (Плавающая ошибка) - SlackWare Linux

Tags: linux, dell, slackware

Имеется старенький сервер: DELL r210 (носитель заменили на SSD диск).

Суть заключается в плавающей проблеме - которая возникает периодически без каких либо причин (Обычно работает абсолютно верно и нет нареканий - кроме того, что есть данная поблема)

При загрузке ОС происходит зависание на некоторых моментах (СКРИН 1 и СКРИН 2 ). 
RAID выключен; 
ОС - SlackWare

[image: Зависание ВАРИАНТЫ 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Индикация на сервере во время зависания (панель индикации 3) 
Possible processor failure (по мануалу)

Comment: т.е., вообще никаких ошибок, просто компьютер остнавливается и всё? значит, настала пора отправить компьютер в музей вычислительной техники.

Comment: Просто в процессе загрузки ОС (один раз из трех загрузок) зависает на одном из двух моментов и все, мертвый груз...